# Highcharts zoom issue after upgrading to jQuery 1.8

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I use Highcharts 2.2.5 to draw a number of area and bar charts.

I Just upgraded my app to jQuery 1.8 and started testing all my charts. 
All appear ok, but when I zoom an area chart, I get tons (literally hundreds) of JavaScript errors saying "`Error: Problem parsing d=0.99030204037363`" (numbers change, sometimes `d=1`) and on the screen all I see are a bunch of dots where the chart was.
Resetting the zoom doesn't work either (yielding more errors, and no result). The only recourse at that point is to reload the page.

I tried looking online for any clashes between HC 2.2.5 and jQuery 1.8 but couldn't find anything. Switching back to jQuery 1.7.2 solves the problem, but still, one must look ahead...

Any assistance is appreciated,
Guy

Comment: You may need to stick with 1.7.2 until Highcharts is updated with support for jQuery 1.8.  It is nice to be able to keep up with the latest version of jQuery, but it's nicer to have things not break :)

Comment: I browsed through their changelog, and the only reason I did upgrade was that it mentioned 1.8 support was added to HC 2.2.4. Guess I have to wait for full support... :(

Comment: you may want to see if you can [submit an issue](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues) with Highcharts. As jQuery 1.8 is so new, it could be that not very many people have run into the same issue you have, or that it hasn't been reported yet.

Comment: Submitted issue and posted message on HC forum. Hoping for fast results, as jq1.8 does seem much faster in other aspects.

Comment: Probably they will close as `can't reproduce` if you don't provide a sample or explain how to get the error. Here is the link for who wants to follow.
https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1181

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reporting the bug on github, per @MrObrian's suggestion, I got this reply:

> It is already fixed for the next release - see
>   http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/GJ4wR/. We're running the final tests
>   on that code now, hope to have it out by next week.

So all I have to do is wait 1 week :)

Comment: BTW, v 2.3.1 fixed everything!

Comment: @travelling Tech Guy..awesome